# Drupal exposed filter to work across different displays

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-exposed-filter, hook-form-alter

I am building a property search and want my exposed filter to work across different view displays. I have 3 views pages, 1 for Grid, 1 for list and 1 for map and I would like the filter to work across these 3 pages.

Here's an example of what I am trying to achieve...
Grid: https://www.onthemarket.com/for-sale/property/london/?view=grid
Map: https://www.onthemarket.com/for-sale/property/london/?view=map
List: https://www.onthemarket.com/for-sale/property/london/

By clicking the relevant icons you get a different displays but the filter still applies and works for those displays.

Any idea how this can be achieved with Views?

Comment: you want the filters to apply or not to apply, as I see the filters are working fine on the page

Answer (score 0):

Just make same exposed filters (with same fields) at all your 3 page views, they will display just like that

Comment: I think I might end up doing it this way. The reason for it working across more than page was to switch out the content with ajax but having the filter remain. Allowed for an overall better user experience